# How can I merge Excel files as separated spreadsheets but respecting the formatting of the original sheets with Python?

Tags: python, excel, spreadsheet

I have tried to merge several Excel files into one workbook with Python and I have only found different methods that only merge all the data into one sheet.

What I need to do is to merge all the Excel files from the current directory subfolders into one workbook, but adding each sheet of each Excel file as a separated worksheet.

If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried a solution with Pandas provided by another user, but the bad thing about it is that it does not respect format like, for example, cell color, font type, box size and border, and so on. This is very important because it is the format that our client uses, so I cannot ignore it, but thank you for the answer!

Is there any workaround with Pandas, Pywin32 or any other Excel library?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, i have created youtube video regarding this query are as  follow.

https://youtu.be/-ywT659M-c4
the file basically go to selected directory and open file and copy all sheet data into one active file.
if you need this automated file then please comment on youtube video so i can share that automated file with you on the basis of youtube comments

Comment: Thanks! But I am not using VBA, I am using Python. I know Pywin32 is using VBA, but I cannot use exactly the same code for my script.